# Error during compilation in magento2 .3 Incompatible argument type: Required type:

Tags: magento2.3, error, di, setup-di-compile, compilation

Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Order\Pdf\Creditmemo
Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface; File:
/var/www/html/app/code/Webkul/Marketplace/Model/Order/Pdf/Creditmemo.php

Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment
Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface; File:
/var/www/html/app/code/Webkul/Marketplace/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php

```
    Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
            Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface; File:
```

/var/www/html/app/code/Webkul/Marketplace/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using the version of extension which is not compatible with your current Magento version.

The constructor for class Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment differs as follows

Magento 2.4.1

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    Config $pdfConfig,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation,
    array $data = []
)
```

Magento 2.3.4

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    Config $pdfConfig,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
    array $data = []
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ask the Webkul support team to resolve it for you and also try to find and replace `\Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface` with `\Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation` because it says that whatever class constructor you are extending (preference) passing required Emulation instead of ResolverInterface